# JAVA executable assertion to test precondition

Tags: java, assertion

I am new to Java and trying to learn some things with online materials.
For one case I should write an assertion to verify preconditions of an operation.

```
public String getCategory(float price, float size, float weight)
```

The preconditions are that all these should be positive.
I don't know where to start.
How do I write this?

Comment: [Programming With Assertions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
public String getCategory(float price, float size, float weight) {
    assert price >= 0 && size >= 0 && weight >= 0: "Invalid parameters";
}
```

Of if you want a more in-detail error message:

```
public String getCategory(float price, float size, float weight) {
   assert price >= 0: "price < 0";
   assert size >= 0: "size < 0";
   assert weight >= 0: "weight < 0";
}
```

When you want a program to run with enabled assertions, run it with the option -ea, e. g:

```
java -ea MyMainClass
```

Don't forget that your better off with using exceptions when checking for bounds when your program is used by others. I only use assertions when coding, because others will probably not run your code with enabled assertions.
Hope this helps, it's my first answer.

Comment: Thanks that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try using if-condition

```
public String getCategory(float price, float size, float weight){
    if(price < 0) {
       // do something or throw exception
    }
}
```

, or using assertion, if the price is negative will give "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Not valid"

```
public String getCategory(float price, float size, float weight){
  assert price >= 0 : "Not valid";
}
```

Comment: Code needs to be compiled with assertions enabled and also executed with assertions enabled, correct?

Comment: This also helped me to understand and I learned something new.